# Searching for linear algebra libs for distributed computing

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am dying to find a C/C++ library for *inverting a large matrix in a distributed environment*. So I would like to ask for recommendations, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135892/is-there-a-library-for-linear-algebra-matrix-handling-in-java) question, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380371/what-are-the-most-widely-used-c-vector-matrix-math-linear-algebra-libraries-a?rq=1) one. However, I can understand that SO is not the place to ask.

So, is there any other site that I can ask? (Like there is Tex for Latex).

---

Here is the [question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/linear-algebra-c-c-library-for-distributed-computing) in the relevant site!

Comment: @gnat good catch, I am voting for this to close, damn should have searched better!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the only site where recommendations are on topic is [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (the clue is in the title!).

However, don't just post any old mess as a question. Check out their "how to ask" page, their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/46), and take a good look at some existing questions to make sure you ask a **good** question.

Comment: Chris sorry for the bad question and thanks for bothering answering. :)

Comment: @G.Samaras - it's not a bad question. Finding duplicates - particularly when you are using different search terms - is hard.